# It takes a long time to show variable fields in openoffice when designing a report

Tags: field, odoo, openoffice.org

I design reports in openOffice with the plugin -- base_report_designer. But when i wanna `add a field` ,It takes a very long time to load the `variable fields`. I don't think it is normal, but i don't have a clue where the problem could be.

plus, I am in windows and the openerp version is 7.

can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a normal behavior as it queries each and every field of the object till 2nd level objects of associated objects.

For example, if you are making a report for invoice, it will fetch all fields for invoice + fields for partner + fields for country.

Comment: It's not effcient. What is your way of designing reports? Could you tell me? Direct rml programing? Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, direct RML programming is the best way, if you can do it, it's most easier and quicker way, similar to HTML programming.

Comment: But it is not convenient if I want to preview the result or debug, isn't it ? Do you have any tool to accelerate the process of development? Thanks.

Comment: yes, that's true. Report debugging is painfull, but you can develop block by block where you'll be able to preview it while development with less surprises.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take your advice.